# Getting list from Many to One Relationship Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models like these:

```
class User(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     username= model.CharField(max_length=25)

class Book(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     book_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     created_by = models.ForeingKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then, I have a rest api with json for getting all books.

```
def get_book_list(request):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    
    return JsonResponse({
          'result_list' : list(queryset.values()) 
    })
```

Now, this api returns json like this:

```
{
      "result_list" : [
                       { "id" : 1, "book_name" : "A-Book", "created_by_id" : 1},
                       { "id" : 2, "book_name" : "B-Book", "created_by_id" : 1},
                       { "id" : 3, "book_name" : "C-Book", "created_by_id" : 1}
                      ]
}
```

I have user that id is 1, username is "Test".

But, api does not return foreign key user object. Why?

Is it possible to getting list like this ? :

```
{
     "result_list" : [
                       { "id" : 1, 
                         "book_name" : "A-Book", 
                         "created_by" : { "id" : 1, "username" : "Test"}
                       },
                       { "id" : 2, 
                         "book_name" : "B-Book", 
                         "created_by" : { "id" : 1, "username" : "Test"}
                       },
                       { "id" : 3, 
                         "book_name" : "C-Book", 
                         "created_by" : { "id" : 1, "username" : "Test"}
                       }
                     ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119119/acess-foreign-key-on-django-template-from-queryset-values/18119307).

Comment: yes I can get the username id and value. but I can not create json string what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **str** method to your User model.

Like this:

```py
class User(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     username= model.CharField(max_length=25)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.username
```

Im not sure is this going to solve your problem, but that's the only thing that comes to my mind right now.